# Issue with tasks not picking up correct ruby version

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, rbenv

This issues comes a goes depending on the Ruby project I'm working on. VSCode Tasks often do not run from the proper `rbenv` shimmed Ruby version. Sometimes, if I manually run a command from the integrated terminal first, then run the Code task it picks up the correct Ruby.

Example VSCode Task,

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Run All Tests",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "bin/rails test",
      "group": "test",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "shared"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When launching Code from the project directory (or any other way for that matter) if I run this task it runs from the context of the System ruby. However, if I open the integrated terminal and type `bin/rails test` (which works) then run the task again it will run in the proper `rbenv` shimmed ruby context.

Launching a debugger session however does work in the proper Ruby context, so I really don't understand what's being missed.

Comment: Run `bundle exec rake task` to explicitly enforce the proper env.

Comment: @mudasobwa yeah that doesn't actually work in this case either. For the sake of brevity I didn't include every permutation of the task that has been tried.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to add the following config to your VSCode `settings.json` to have the shells that it launches pick up your shell environment before executing the task. Here I'm using `zsh` and my environment is configured to pick up the right ruby, which tasks will then recognize:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": { "zsh": { "path": "/bin/zsh", "args": ["-l", "-i"] } }
```

Comment: saved me a day. In Visual code editor. Open the command palette (command+shift+P) and type Open User settings (JSON), add the line suggested by @Denis

Answer (score 1):

This answer will get tasks working, however it doesn't fix the underlying problem with VS Code. This probably needs to be an issue posted on their GitHub repo.

If you're on a Mac, this command will put a ruby symlink in your path that links to the rbenv version. Rbenv (and most applications) only change the path inside a shell environment (the .bash_profile only changes it for bash). This command will add it to the path regardless of what shell you run.

```
ln -s "/Users/$(whoami)/.rbenv/shims/ruby" /usr/local/bin/ruby
```

My guess is that VS Code is not actually using a shell environment and is instead calling the executable directly.

Answer (score 0):

Until Visual Studio Code solves what seems to be a bug or missing configuration setting or, at least, missing documentation, I have resorted to setting the `PATH` variable on the task's `command` attribute.

For example, if the ruby I'm interested in using is at `/full/path/to/bin/ruby`, I prepend `/full/path/to/bin` to the `PATH` environment variable.

For example:

**.vscode/tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
    {
        "label": "sidekiq",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "export PATH=/full/path/to/bin:$PATH && bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml",
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "always",
            "panel": "dedicated"
        },
        "runOptions": {
            "runOn": "folderOpen"
        }
    }]
}
```